# GroupBy in LINQ returns different results than in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by

I am using the following function to remove the duplicate values in an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` based on one or more fields:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRow> RemoveDuplicates(this IEnumerable<DataRow> rows, IEnumerable<string> fields)
{
    return rows
        .GroupBy(row => new MultiFieldComparer(fields.Select(f => row[f])))
        .Select(g => g.First());
}
```

E.g. if fields are `firstname`,`lastname` and `email` the function, using a LINQ `GroupBy` will return only values who have a distinct value of `firstname`, `lastname`, and `email`;

When I try to simulate this behavior on my database using the following query
I get different number of results:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,email 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY firstname,lastname,email
```

In my function I am taking advantage of a `MultiFieldComparer` that I use to do the comparison based on more than one field. Here is the code to this class:

```
public class MultiFieldComparer : IEquatable<IEnumerable<object>>, IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<object>>
{
    private IEnumerable<object> objects;

    public MultiFieldComparer(IEnumerable<object> objects)
    {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<object> x, IEnumerable<object> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<object> objects)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (object obj in objects)
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj == null ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode());
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetHashCode(this.objects);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MultiFieldComparer other = obj as MultiFieldComparer;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.Equals(this.objects, other.objects);
    }

    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<object> other)
    {
        return this.Equals(this.objects, other);
    }
}
```

I would like to know where the difference comes from?

Comment: One possibility I can think of is that by using an `IEnumerable<object>` you are actually comparing strings by reference in the `SequenceEquals` method.

Comment: also sql is generally case insensitive

Comment: @Ewan I actually want my function to be case insensitive too. Is there a way I can handle it in my comparison somehow?

Comment: @Ewan you were right. When I turned all my values to lowercase, the numbers got equal. You can post this as an answer if you want.